# SOQL: No response from the server error

Tags: soql, query, developer-console, workbench, debug

I have below query to run either in workbench or Developer console, query editor.
While on workbench, I get **error**: `UNKNOWN ERROR: Error Fetching http headers` 
and in **Developer console error as** `No response from the server`

Can someone please let me know what's wrong in my query?

***Query***

```
SELECT count() 
FROM Affiliation_vod__c 
Where From_Account_vod__c in ( SELECT Account_vod__c 
                 FROM TSF_vod__c 
                 WHERE DM_Show_Offline_abv__c = 'Yes' ) 
and (To_Account_vod__r.Name != null 
    OR From_Account_vod__r.Name != null 
    OR To_Contact_vod__r.Name != null 
    or From_Contact_vod__r.Name != null)
```

Comment: Suggest you start with just the `SELECT count() 
FROM Affiliation_vod__c` and add back in the `WHERE` term bit by bit to identify the problem piece. If there are large numbers of `Affiliation_vod__c` or `TSF_vod__c` objects you may be hitting "Too Many Query Rows" limits that are failing to be reported back to you correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens when you are querying records on an object which has huge amount of records (i.e. in lacs). In your case, the how many total records you have in Affiliation_vod__c object? If the total records are in lacs and you are querying few out of them, you may face this issue.

Comment: In India, lacs or lakhs is a number. 
1 lac = 100,000 and 10 lacs = 1 million.

Comment: What do you do if you are in this situation? Limiting the queries does not seem to help or resolve anything. I put a limit of "40" on mine and it still did not run.